# Calculate the FFT of wav file in c

Tags: c, fftw

I have a mono wav file that plays two frequency in different time; 400 Hz on the first second and 300 Hz afters it.

When trying to perform a DFT on this mono wav file that has a length of 3 seconds and has a sample rate of 44100, FFTW seems to only perform a DFT on the first 1 second of the audio:

[image: 400 Hz]
my_plan:

```
fftw_plan my_plan = fftw_plan_dft_1d(SampleRate, in, out, FFTW_FORWARD, FFTW_ESTIMATE);
fftw_execute(my_plan);
```

Of course, it's due to the first argument of the function `fftw_plan_dft_1d` being a 'SampleRate', BUT! If I change it to the number of samples of the wav_file then this would mess up the position of the correct frequency:

[image: Mess frequency]

But how to perform a DFT on all 3 seconds or something that is little like .5 seconds?

If you need elaboration, please ask.

Comment: The first argument is not sample rate, it’s the size of the transform. And the results you get will be based on that and you will have to calculate which frequency is at which spot, which is a simple division operation. This is how FFT works.

Comment: If you do FFT on three times more samples then you get three times more results and if you want a specific frequency you look at the index of frequency times three. Like you see on your second graph the peaks are at 900 and 1200, so divide by three and it’s 300 and 400

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen Thank you very much! that was easy peasy!